How to finish the kotlin flow from inside the method called in this flow?
sorry for any mistakes and my english, it is my first question here (feedback welcome :) )
I have got a method that returns a flow. This flow at first emits Resource.Loading, then emits the expected result or an AppError. After that it should finish its work (so if error occurred, the rest of the flow logic shouldn't be executed). It works like this: "if the error occurred, emit error and return@flow. Otherwise just go on with the flow's logic". It could be solved by using if/else blocks, but it would make the code unreadable if there are multiple error checks (it results in nested if/else blocks).
I've got an idea to make different methods with behaviour similar to void functions for each check. Such a method would just check if there is error and if it is, then the method would emit the error and finish the flow somehow, otherwise the method will do nothing.
The code that already exists:
suspend operator fun invoke(company: Company): Flow<Resource<Unit>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            if (!appUtilityUseCases.isInternetConnectionAvailable()) {
                emit(Resource.Error(AppError.NetworkError()))
                return@flow
            }
            if (company.id == null) {
                Logger.wtf("DeleteCompany::invoke", "CompanyID is null, but can't be!")
                emit(Resource.Error(AppError.CriticalErrors.NullError))
                return@flow
            }

            val doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult = doesCompanyHaveAnyCompanyServiceAssociated(company.id)
            if (doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult is Result.Error) {
                emit(Resource.Error(doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult.error!!))
                return@flow
            } else if (doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult is Result.Success) {
                val doesCompanyOwnsAnyService = doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult.data!!
                if (doesCompanyOwnsAnyService) {
                    emit(Resource.Error(AppError.DataErrors.CanNotDeleteCompanyThatHasCompanyServiceAssociated))
                    return@flow
                }
            }

            companyRepository.getCompany(company.id)
                ?.let { companyWithLogoUrl ->
                    deleteCompanyLogo(companyWithLogoUrl.id, companyWithLogoUrl.logoUrl)
                    deleteCompany(company)
                    Logger.i("DeleteCompany::invoke", "Company deleted: $company")
                    emit(Resource.Success())
                }
        } catch (e: FirebaseNetworkException) {
            Logger.e("DeleteCompany::invoke", "Error occurred while trying to delete company: $company", e)
            emit(Resource.Error(AppError.NetworkError(e)))
        } catch (e: StorageException) {
            Logger.e("DeleteCompany::invoke", "Error occurred while trying to delete company: $company", e)
            emit(Resource.Error(AppError.DataErrors.FirebaseStorageError(e)))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Logger.e("DeleteCompany::invoke", "Error occurred while trying to delete company: $company", e)
            emit(Resource.Error(AppError.CriticalErrors.UnknownError(e)))
        }
    }

    
    private suspend fun doesCompanyHaveAnyCompanyServiceAssociated(companyID: String): Result<Boolean> {
        return companyServiceRepository.doesCompanyOwnAnyCompanyService(companyID)
    }

    private suspend fun  deleteCompany(company: Company) {
        companyRepository.deleteCompany(company)
    }

    private suspend fun deleteCompanyLogo(companyID: String, logoUrl: String?) {
        logoUrl?.let { url -> companyLogoRepository.deleteCompanyLogo(companyID, url) }
    }

This is how I would like it to work, but it is rather a pseudocode because it obviously doesn't work (can not use emit() nor return@flow inside those check methods):
suspend operator fun invoke(company: Company): Flow<Resource<Unit>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            checkInternetConnection() // if there is network error -> emits error and finishing the flow
            checkIfCompanyIDIsNull(company) // if companyID is null -> emits error and finishing the flow
            checkIfCompanyOwnsAnyService(company) // if company owns any service -> emits error and finishing the flow

            companyRepository.getCompany(company.id!!)
                ?.let { companyWithLogoUrl ->
                    deleteCompanyLogo(companyWithLogoUrl.id, companyWithLogoUrl.logoUrl)
                    deleteCompany(company)
                    Logger.i("DeleteCompany::invoke", "Company deleted: $company")
                    emit(Resource.Success()) // emits Success if all checks passed and no exception has been thrown, flow is finished automatically, because there is no logic left to execute
                }
        } catch (e: FirebaseNetworkException) {
            Logger.e("DeleteCompany::invoke", "Error occurred while trying to delete company: $company", e)
            emit(Resource.Error(AppError.NetworkError(e)))
        } catch (e: StorageException) {
            Logger.e("DeleteCompany::invoke", "Error occurred while trying to delete company: $company", e)
            emit(Resource.Error(AppError.DataErrors.FirebaseStorageError(e)))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Logger.e("DeleteCompany::invoke", "Error occurred while trying to delete company: $company", e)
            emit(Resource.Error(AppError.CriticalErrors.UnknownError(e)))
        }
    }

    private suspend fun doesCompanyHaveAnyCompanyServiceAssociated(companyID: String): Result<Boolean> {
        return companyServiceRepository.doesCompanyOwnAnyCompanyService(companyID)
    }

    private suspend fun deleteCompany(company: Company) {
        companyRepository.deleteCompany(company)
    }

    private suspend fun deleteCompanyLogo(companyID: String, logoUrl: String?) {
        logoUrl?.let { url -> companyLogoRepository.deleteCompanyLogo(companyID, url) }
    }

    private fun checkInternetConnection() {
        if (!appUtilityUseCases.isInternetConnectionAvailable()) {
            emit(Resource.Error(AppError.NetworkError()))
            return@flow
        }
    }

    private fun checkIfCompanyIDIsNull(company: Company) {
        if (company.id == null) {
            Logger.wtf("DeleteCompany::invoke", "CompanyID is null, but can't be!")
            emit(Resource.Error(AppError.CriticalErrors.NullError))
            return@flow
        }
    }

    private fun checkIfCompanyOwnsAnyService(company: Company) {
        val doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult = doesCompanyHaveAnyCompanyServiceAssociated(company.id!!)
        // Result is of type Error, sth went wrong in repository (network error, deserialization error etc)
        if (doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult is Result.Error) {
            emit(Resource.Error(doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult.error!!))
            return@flow
        }
        // Repository has succeeded, but in terms of business logic it is an error in the app
        else if (doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult is Result.Success) {
            val doesCompanyOwnsAnyService = doesCompanyOwnsAnyServiceResult.data!!
            if (doesCompanyOwnsAnyService) {
                emit(Resource.Error(AppError.DataErrors.CanNotDeleteCompanyThatHasCompanyServiceAssociated))
                return@flow
            }
        }
    }

sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val error: AppError? = null) {
    class Success<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(error: AppError, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, error)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
}

I was thinking about passing the flow context into check methods as a parameter, but i don't know how to do it properly anyway (and i don't know if it is a good solution). To be honest I am so lost with this problem. It should be good and reusable in other use-cases solution written in accordance with the principles of clean architecture, but i don't even know where to start. Could you help me with that?
PS invoke() method is a method of the use-case class in MVVM android application written with kotlin and Jetpack Compose. It is designed to be called in viewModel. UI reacts to the Resource class states that are emitted in this use case (Resource.Loading, Resource.Success, Resource.Error)

Just make your Resource.Error throwable or create a wrapper class for it that is. Then have your check... methods throw it and then it's just a matter of emitting it. Regardless of how nice flows are, sometimes when I have to collapse (nested) flow executions I just throw and catch it in top-most flow because wrapping and propagating everything in Result-type classes just gets bothersome.

@Pawel do you suggest to catch such thrown exception in invoke() method and emit the error from there?

Essentially. You can also consider changing it to use flows catch{} operator (with a switch) instead of having multiple catch blocks inside of flow itself.

@Pawel oh, it is possible to use .catch{} operator after closing brace of flow builder "in" the invoke method, I didn;t know that. Does it differ somehow from traditional try/catch block?
BTW i have edited original question and added implementation for Resource class. Could you provide implementation for such a wrapper class for Resource.Error that you mentioned? I would like to see how good implementation should look like.

Typically, as in this case, it does not make sense for a function that returns a flow to be marked suspend.

@Tenfour04 I was thinking about it, but wasn't sure. Could you explain why?

Declaration of flow by itself does not suspend - it's the act of collecting it that does.

It’s a simple object that is trivial to create and does nothing until collect() is called on it later. And often you want to be passing them around and working with them in non-suspending code, like in property initializers.
